# jekyll won't process markdown even with non-BOM files

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to set up a simple blog on via Visual Studio and Jekyll but Jekyll can't seem to parse markdown for my posts correctly. Here's the result for my file as is.

[image]

Notice that per Visual Studio, this currently is saved with BOM but still builds.

[image]

I'm aware that files need to have NO BOM (Byte Order Marker) so I've tried saving it without it but still can't get any results. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

**EDIT**: Here's backtrace output per comments:

[image]

**EDIT2:** I've tried all the possible line endings available and still can't seem to get anything going. Per @Waylan 's comments I looked into [issue #3304](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3304) but it seems it isn't fully resolved. [Check out this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5468) if you'd like to add any comments

[image]

Comment: Do you have any output from backtrace? "jekyll serve -t"

Comment: @MattRinger just added it but there's no errors being reported or anything. Do you know of a way to get more verbose logging from Jekyll offhand?

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to line endings. Might want to see [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3304) which was apparently fixed in Jekyll 3. Could give you some debugging tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was occurring because I was adding via Visual Studio.

**You must add the files as a regular text file in Windows Explorer - then you'll be able to edit them in Visual Studio as you like**.

Hopefully we'll get support for this in later version of Jekyll or Visual Studio will change whatever it is that's causing the issue. I've made note of the issue with Jekyll already [here though](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5468) if anyone would like to add on to it